# Difference between jQuery's attr() and getAttribute()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The jQuery documention for the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method states that:

> Attribute values are strings with the exception of a few attributes
>   such as value and tabindex.

And that does seem to be the case. Consider the following element:

```
<input type="text" id="example" tabindex="3">
```

The following line does indeed show "number", not "string":

```
alert(typeof $("#example").attr("tabindex")); //Number
```

Now, the thing that's confusing me is that when using the DOM method `getAttribute`, you get a different result:

```
alert(typeof $("#example")[0].getAttribute("tabindex")); //String
```

Looking at the jQuery source for the `attr` method, it appears that jQuery simply returns what `getAttribute` returns, so why is there a difference? Here's the [relevant lines of the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L345):

```
ret = elem.getAttribute( name );
// Non-existent attributes return null, we normalize to undefined
return ret === null ?
         undefined :
         ret;
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/FcusH/) to demonstrate the issue. Just to confuse matters further, I've tried it in Chrome 15, Firefox 8, IE8 and IE7, and all behave as described above, except for IE7, which alerts "number" for both (which is what I would expect to happen).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because jQuery defines a [propHook for `tabIndex`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b4392c220af3da945a8b2d7b0053291956c97a17/src/attributes.js#L469) which explicity [`parseInt`'s the return type](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b4392c220af3da945a8b2d7b0053291956c97a17/src/attributes.js#L476);

```
return attributeNode && attributeNode.specified ?
  parseInt( attributeNode.value, 10 ) :
  rfocusable.test( elem.nodeName ) || rclickable.test( elem.nodeName ) && elem.href ?
    0 :
    undefined;
```

This hook is then [added to the `attrHook`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b4392c220af3da945a8b2d7b0053291956c97a17/src/attributes.js#L486) which is why the behaviour is observed in the `attr` function (and why it first appears [no attrHook is defined for `tabIndex`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b4392c220af3da945a8b2d7b0053291956c97a17/src/attributes.js#L378)).

Comment: Ahh, that'll teach me for not looking a bit further up and properly following the jQuery source! Thanks.

Comment: You should link to a certain tag, instead of the master branch. Otherwise the line numbers might change in the future.