# Javascript image src attribute returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, src

I have a little javascript code attached to a button with onclick to the following code:

```
function ondelete () {

    var getDiv = document.getElementById("imgdiv");
    var lb_img = $("#imgdiv").children();
    for (var i = 0; i < lb_img.length; i++) {
        console.log(lb_img[i].src);
    }
}
```

This returns a single output which is great, this is the corresponding html when opened in chrome with F12 developers tool:

```
<div id="imgdiv" class="modal-body next">
    <img draggable="false"src="http://(urlfrommywebsite)/A_LANX/get/OTc1/179f42">
</div>
```

So the code should return that src attribute, but instead it returns

```
http://127.0.0.1/stage/local/admin/galleries/gallery/2
```

which is my url. On other images it returns the value of another img or this same url, really weird. This all happens inside a lightbox, so the normal code without a lightbox open is

```
<div id="imgdiv" class="modal-body next"></div>
```

I'm really stuck here, so a little help is really usefull :)

EDIT:

No answer seems to help so far, any recommendations for other lightboxes with maybe a function like getImage() or something simular?

p.s. fancybox doesn't quitte work for me either.

Comment: https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/ This is the image gallery used

Comment: Please provide fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's attr() to get attributes

```
$("img").attr("src");
```

Edit the selector accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/b3xdgn83/1

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced in javascript, how do i edit the selector accordingly?

Comment: I just selected all images but you can specify id's or classes.

Comment: For some reason attr doesn't work for me, getAttribute does, is this the same, because getAttribute doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using this code to get the image url.

```
<div id="imgdiv" class="modal-body next">
<img draggable="false" src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/31/33/51/black-background_00313351.jpg">
```

jQuery Code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert($('#imgdiv img').attr('src'));
```

});

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/7sqkrcj3/)

Comment: I keep having the same issues, it has probably something to do with the  lightbox, but it doesn't have a getimage function or something like that in it's api, very annoying.

Comment: You image path getting in any data attribute ?

Comment: and used live() Or ON() jQuery function

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
function ondelete() {

        var lb_img = $("#imgdiv").children();
        for (var i = 0; i < lb_img.length; i++) {
            console.log(lb_img[i].getAttribute("src"));
        }
    }
```

for more info about attr() and getAttribute() see this post:[Difference between jQuery's attr() and getAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149203/difference-between-jquerys-attr-and-getattribute)