# how to get a specific button id in an array of images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to only get the parent button id of an image in the array with the specific `src` of srcA. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('con').getElementsByTagName('img');
var myImg = [];
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if (images[i].src == "srcA")
    myImg.push(images[i]);
  alert(images[i].parent.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
  <button id="ba"><img id="sa" src="srcA"></button>
  <button id="bb"><img id="sb" src="srcB"></button>
  <button id="bc"><img id="sc" src="srcC"></button>
  <button id="bd"><img id="sd" src="srcD"></button>
  <button id="be"><img id="se" src="srcE"></button>
  <button id="bf"><img id="sf" src="srcF"></button>
</div>
```

I get an error `images[i].parent` is undefined

No jQuery please.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#con img[src="srcA"]')`

Comment: Try `parentNode` (not `parent`)

Comment: @Scrimothy   parentNode does return the id. thanks for that but it still returns the whole array instead of just the specific source.  Im trying to get one id back for the button wrapping the specific image source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the parent div of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element)

Comment: @HereticMonkey The alert issue is kind of secondary, the main problem is the `if` not wrapping both commands and `.src` yielding the full URL. So not a duplicate imo.

Comment: @ChrisG Certainly you're aware of how we deal with proposed duplicates? [Edit] the question to show how the duplicate is different, or better (in this case) close as a duplicate of a different question (e.g., [Javascript image src attribute returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27201078/215552)) or as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var images = document.getElementById('con').getElementsByTagName('img');
var myImg = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
if(images[i].getAttribute("src") == "srcA"){
  myImg.push(images[i]);
  alert(images[i].parentNode.id);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
<button id="ba"><img id="sa" src="srcA"></button>
<button id="bb"><img id="sb" src="srcB"></button>
<button id="bc"><img id="sc" src="srcC"></button>
<button id="bd"><img id="sd" src="srcD"></button>
<button id="be"><img id="se" src="srcE"></button>
<button id="bf"><img id="sf" src="srcF"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured it out with the help of John and Chris G.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just use:

```
var imgSRCAParent = document.querySelector("img[src='srcA']").parentElement;
```

I checked it out and it works.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must combine `querySelector` and attributes from parent.

```
function findParent (source) {
  return document.querySelector("#con button img[src="+source+"]").parentElement.id;
}
```

using like this:

```
findParent("srcA"); // its return "ba"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two errors

1. If statement is missing curly brace
2. src is relative URL so you
   need to add it to the check

Of course, adding static URL check like that is a bad idea, so either use a getAttribute as mentioned in the comments or do a / split

```js
var images = document.getElementById('con').getElementsByTagName('img');
var myImg = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
if(images[i].src === "https://stacksnippets.net/srcA"){
  myImg.push(images[i]);
  alert(images[i].id);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
<button id="ba"><img id="sa" src="srcA"></button>
<button id="bb"><img id="sb" src="srcB"></button>
<button id="bc"><img id="sc" src="srcC"></button>
<button id="bd"><img id="sd" src="srcD"></button>
<button id="be"><img id="se" src="srcE"></button>
<button id="bf"><img id="sf" src="srcF"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Or use `images[i].getAttribute("src") == "srcA"`, but otherwise is this the only answer that properly addresses the issues with the question's code.

Comment: This is very close i figured it out add @Chris G's  images[i].getAttribute("src") == instead of images[i].src ===  and  alert(images[i].parentNode.id) to the alert and Ill mark it correct.  Chris G was right this answer is closest to the problem. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that value of `src` in Javascript is the same was the string you put into the `src` attribute in the HTML. Javascript has already expanded it out to a fully recognizable URL complete with protocol and domain. You have to separate the `src` so that you can grab *just* the last portion that you put in there. Then evaluate against the path you targeted.

This was a good place for a simple `console.log()` debugging.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('con').getElementsByTagName('img');
var myImg = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  const path = images[i].src.split('/');
  const lastStop = path[path.length - 1];
  if(lastStop == "srcA") {
    myImg.push(images[i]);
    alert(images[i].parentNode.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
<button id="ba"><img id="sa" src="srcA"></button>
<button id="bb"><img id="sb" src="srcB"></button>
<button id="bc"><img id="sc" src="srcC"></button>
<button id="bd"><img id="sd" src="srcD"></button>
<button id="be"><img id="se" src="srcE"></button>
<button id="bf"><img id="sf" src="srcF"></button>
</div>
```